# Would like a radio based tracking system for sports games to track athletes position on ice/field/court

Tags: tracking-devices, asset-tracking

I cannot find a reasonably priced system that would simply triangulate players on a field/ice/court. Say 50 total players. Would anyone have some thoughts on building such a system?